# Query Error when Saving Image ModelForm in Django

Tags: python, django, image, model

I'm trying to make a simple image upload form, which works until I try to save the Model called User_Image using the posted data. The error I get is this: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'QueryDict' and I receive it at the line marked ***********. Thanks for the help.

models.py:

```
class User_Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="img") 
    user_profile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

forms.py:

```
class User_ImageForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
         model = User_Image
```

views.py:

```
def upload_image(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       HttpResponseRedirect("/accounts/profile")
       form = User_ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
       if form.is_valid():
          im = User_Image(request.POST, request.FILES)
          ******im = im.save()
          HttpResponseRedirect("/accounts/profile")
       else:
          form = User_ImageForm()
       return render_to_response('uploadimage.html', {'form':form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you saving it to the model class directly? Try:

```
form = User_ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
if form.is_valid():
    im = form.save()
    HttpResponseRedirect("/accounts/profile")
```

Comment: Also hopefully your have named urls so `HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('account-profile'))`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to following lines.

```
im = User_Image(request.POST, request.FILES)
im = im.save()
```

Enough to save the form,

```
.....
if form.is_valid():
   form.save()
   HttpResponseRedirect("/accounts/profile")
.....
```